# Change keyboard language in Android programmatically

Tags: android

I want which keyboard is now active like English,Hindi
 and change it dynamically..

```
List<InputMethodInfo> InputMethods = imeManager.getEnabledInputMethodList();

for(int i=0;i<InputMethods.size();i++)
{
    String s1=InputMethods.get(i).loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
    String s2=InputMethods.get(i).getServiceName().toString();

    Toast.makeText(Display1.this, s2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

if (imeManager != null) 
{
    imeManager.showInputMethodPicker();
}
else 
{
    Toast.makeText(Display1.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for questions, and this is not a question.

Comment: see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/android-sdk-support_r11/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/keyboard/KeyboardSwitcher.java